# Prevent swiperight event from hammerjs with carousel slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js (v2.0.8) to show the left menu but I also have a carousel in the same page (with owl carousel v2.3.4). When I slide the carousel, the menu open too. I try `Hammer.off()` but he doesn't work.

This is the Hammer event (in the global js so for all pages):

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(document.body);
hammertime.on('swiperight', function(ev) {
    //my function here
});
```

And I want to disable the event when touching this element :

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme " id="events"><DYNAMIC_SLIDE_HERE></div>
```

How to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find a way to solve this by checking class :

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(document.body);
hammertime.on('swiperight', function(e) {
    if(!e.target.classList.contains("item-carousel")){
        //do my function        
    }
});
```